# CKFinder 2.x: specific permissions for files

Tags: permissions, ckeditor, acl, ckfinder

Is there a way for me to specify that certain files can be deleted by a user, and others can't be deleted, in the same folder? Please note that I'm talking about FILES, and not FOLDERS.

For example:

1. FolderA contains 5 files: File1, File2, File3, File4, File5
2. UserA has permissions to delete File1, File3, File5, but does NOT have permissions to delete File2 and File4.
3. UserA should not be able to delete File2 and File4

I've tried checking the API, and there's some information on ACL, but it applies to the folder (if the folder ACL has FileDelete as true, means that the files on that folder can be deleted).

API: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.dataTypes.Acl.html

Example of ACL configuration:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Configuration/Access_Control

Thanks!

Comment: The ACL rules in CKFinder are defined for folders, so it's not possible to define a rule that will work with your example (unless you move File2 and File4 to another folder). The scenario you described would require adding some modifications on the connector side, it's not supported by default. You can check the the `HideFiles` option in connector - File2 and File4 could be hidden for UserA, but I'm not sure if it makes sense for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info! No, hiding them does not what I need, because I need to use them (select them), I just want to avoid the deletion.